# Quotation marks inside a string

Tags: java, string

I need some help from you guys. I have a string  `name = "john"`

But I want to save this String name as `"john"`, including `""`(quotations)

```
String name = ""john"";
String name1 = "[john]"
```

Can some one help me with this.

Comment: What does that `"[john]"` mean? Is this another example?

Comment: Yes, its another example, But what if i want to use variable name directly, I mean can i use "\"+name+\"" like this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
String name = "\"john\"";
```

You have to escape the second pair of quotation marks using the \ character in front. It might be worth looking at [this link](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0050.html), which explains in some detail.

Other scenario where you set variable:

```
String name2 = "\""+name+"\"";
```

Sequence in console:

```
> String name = "\"john\"";
> name
""john""
> String name2 = "\""+name+"\"";
> name2
"""john"""
```

Comment: But what if i want to use variable name directly, I mean can i use "\"+name+\"" like this.

Comment: Complete answer for this question and other answers MUST DELETE.

Answer (score 10):

You need to escape the quotation marks:

```
String name = "\"john\"";
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add escaped double quotes like this: `String name = "\"john\"";`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Escape Sequence.

`\"`

So you will have to write something like this :

```
String name = "\"john\"";
```

You can learn about Escape Sequences from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).