# Quotes around a defined variable name

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

So I understand how to print quotes around something like "Hello" using system.out.println
for example:

```
System.out.print("\"Hello\"");
```

to get "Hello"

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to print quotes around a variable.
I've tried for example:

```
String test = "Hello";

System.out.print("\test\, ");
```

If anyone has tips, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quotation marks inside a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354168/quotation-marks-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
System.out.print("\"" + test + "\"");
```

You're not printing the variable inside a string, but by itself, so it's outside of the format quotes. And you print quotes escaped, just like you did in your first string; just enclose them in their own quotes.

Comment: Ahh! Concatenation.. Brilliant! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do that,

```
String test = "Hello";
```

and then

```
System.out.println("\"" + test + "\"");
```

or

```
System.out.printf("\"%s\"%n", test);
```

or write a method to add quotes,

```
private static String quoteString(String in) {
  return String.format("\"%s\"", in);
}
```

then

```
System.out.println(quoteString(test));
```

Or perhaps

```
String test = quoteString("Hello");
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

To print the variable value enclosed in quotes, you have to concatenate the quotes:

```
System.out.println("\"" + test + "\"");
```